# Keep the order of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that could contain zero values.

```
$array = array(3=> 1000, 5=> 0, 6=> 5000, 7 => 0);
```

Since the code that uses that array can't manage fields set as 0, I need to remove them. (I thought to store the field with 0 as value in a temp array):

```
$zero_array = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $s) {
    $zero_array[$k] = $k;
    unset($stack[$k]);
}
```

After the core code has runned I want to put back the filed that had 0 as value in the same position as they were.

The core code returns an array like this:

```
$output = array(3 => 10, 6 => 50);
```

I'd like to add the old keys and get this:

```
$output = array(3 => 10, 5 => 0, 6 => 50, 7 => 0);
```

Comment: Tried array_merge($output,$zero_array) ?

Comment: Keep your original array the way it is, then create a copy of that array without the 0 values to use in your code. You can unset() that array when your code has completed use of it and you still have your original for whatever else you need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) in this situation to remove the 0 values:

```
$old_array = array(3 => 1000, 5=> 0, 6=> 5000, 7 => 0);
$new_array = array_filter($old_array);

// Now: $new_array = Array ( [3] => 1000 [6] => 5000 )
```

Then, do the stuff you want to `$new_array`

```
// Core code: Divide each element by 100:
$new_array = array(3 => 10, 6 => 50);
```

Then use the [array union operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) followed by [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) to get your desired array:

```
$array = $new_array + $old_array;
ksort($array);

// Now: Array ( [3] => 10 [5] => 0 [6] => 50 [7] => 0 )
```

Note: If `Array ( [3] => 10 [6] => 50 [5] => 0 [7] => 0 )` is acceptable (IE. all the same key value pairs as your desired array, just in a different order), then you can skip the call to ksort.